# C# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject returning null values for a json array of objects

Tags: c#, json, class, serialization, json.net

I have a JSON string that I want to deserialize in an C# object

The JSON is a array of objects with five identical objects without names.

When I try to deserialize with the  command:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.AuxilioEmergencial>>(restResponse.Content);`

I get a list with the five object but all of them null:
[Print of Visual Studio Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rulmg.png)

take a look in JSON:

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "mesDisponibilizacao": "06/2020",
        "beneficiario": 
        {
            "nis": "123",
            "nome": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "multiploCadastro": false,
            "cpfFormatado": "***.862.400-**"
        },
    "responsavelAuxilioEmergencial": 
        {
            "nis": "123",
            "nome": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "nomeSemAcento": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "cpfFormatado": "***.862.400-**"
        },
    "municipio": 
        {
            "codigoIBGE": "123",
            "nomeIBGE": "LAST TIME I SAW RICHARD",
            "nomeIBGEsemAcento": "LAST TIME I SAW RICHARD",
            "pais": "BRASIL",
            "uf": 
            {
                "sigla": "RS",
                "nome": "RIO GRANDE DO SUL"
            }
        },
    "valor": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "mesDisponibilizacao": "06/2020",
        "beneficiario": 
        {
            "nis": "123",
            "nome": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "multiploCadastro": false,
            "cpfFormatado": "***.862.400-**"
        },
    "responsavelAuxilioEmergencial": 
        {
            "nis": "123",
            "nome": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "nomeSemAcento": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "cpfFormatado": "***.862.400-**"
        },
    "municipio": 
        {
            "codigoIBGE": "123",
            "nomeIBGE": "LAST TIME I SAW RICHARD",
            "nomeIBGEsemAcento": "LAST TIME I SAW RICHARD",
            "pais": "BRASIL",
            "uf": 
            {
                "sigla": "RS",
                "nome": "RIO GRANDE DO SUL"
            }
        },
    "valor": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "mesDisponibilizacao": "06/2020",
        "beneficiario": 
        {
            "nis": "123",
            "nome": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "multiploCadastro": false,
            "cpfFormatado": "***.862.400-**"
        },
    "responsavelAuxilioEmergencial": 
        {
            "nis": "123",
            "nome": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "nomeSemAcento": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "cpfFormatado": "***.862.400-**"
        },
    "municipio": 
        {
            "codigoIBGE": "123",
            "nomeIBGE": "LAST TIME I SAW RICHARD",
            "nomeIBGEsemAcento": "LAST TIME I SAW RICHARD",
            "pais": "BRASIL",
            "uf": 
            {
                "sigla": "RS",
                "nome": "RIO GRANDE DO SUL"
            }
        },
    "valor": 40
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "mesDisponibilizacao": "06/2020",
        "beneficiario": 
        {
            "nis": "123",
            "nome": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "multiploCadastro": false,
            "cpfFormatado": "***.862.400-**"
        },
    "responsavelAuxilioEmergencial": 
        {
            "nis": "123",
            "nome": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "nomeSemAcento": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "cpfFormatado": "***.862.400-**"
        },
    "municipio": 
        {
            "codigoIBGE": "123",
            "nomeIBGE": "LAST TIME I SAW RICHARD",
            "nomeIBGEsemAcento": "LAST TIME I SAW RICHARD",
            "pais": "BRASIL",
            "uf": 
            {
                "sigla": "RS",
                "nome": "RIO GRANDE DO SUL"
            }
        },
    "valor": 40
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "mesDisponibilizacao": "06/2020",
        "beneficiario": 
        {
            "nis": "123",
            "nome": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "multiploCadastro": false,
            "cpfFormatado": "***.862.400-**"
        },
    "responsavelAuxilioEmergencial": 
        {
            "nis": "123",
            "nome": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "nomeSemAcento": "JONI MITCHELL",
            "cpfFormatado": "***.862.400-**"
        },
    "municipio": 
        {
            "codigoIBGE": "123",
            "nomeIBGE": "LAST TIME I SAW RICHARD",
            "nomeIBGEsemAcento": "LAST TIME I SAW RICHARD",
            "pais": "BRASIL",
            "uf": 
            {
                "sigla": "RS",
                "nome": "RIO GRANDE DO SUL"
            }
        },
    "valor": 50
    }    
]
```

and My C# class

```
 [public class AuxilioEmergencial 
{
    public  Auxilio\[\] auxilio { get; set; }

}
public class Auxilio
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string mesDisponibilizacao { get; set; }
    public Beneficiario beneficiario { get; set; }
    public Responsavelauxilioemergencial responsavelAuxilioEmergencial { get; set; }
    public DadosMunicipio municipio { get; set; }
    public float valor { get; set; }
}
public class Beneficiario
{
    public string nis { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public bool multiploCadastro { get; set; }
    public string cpfFormatado { get; set; }
}
public class Responsavelauxilioemergencial
{
    public string nis { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string nomeSemAcento { get; set; }
    public string cpfFormatado { get; set; }
}
public class DadosMunicipio
{
    public string codigoIBGE { get; set; }
    public string nomeIBGE { get; set; }
    public string nomeIBGEsemAcento { get; set; }
    public string pais { get; set; }
    public UF uf { get; set; }
}
public class UF
{
    public string sigla { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.AuxilioEmergencial>>(restResponse.Content);
```

You're telling the deserializer that you want a `List`, where every element is of type `AuxilioEmergencial`.

Your class `AuxilioEmergencial` has 1 property `auxilio`, which means every object in the JSON array has to have that property to be properly deserialized. E.g.:

```
[
  {
    "auxilio": {
      "id ": 1,
      "mesDisponibilizacao": "06/2020",
      ...
    }
  },
  {
    "auxilio": {
      ...
    }
  }
]
```

What you actually want is:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Auxilio>>(restResponse.Content);
```

Comment: I'm feeling a little stupid hahaha but thank you very much!! That's worked :)